# Secure asymmetric encryption with 32byte ciphertext

Tags: encryption, public-key, elgamal-encryption

I need securely asymmetrically encrypt the up to 16 bytes plaintext and receive up to 32 bytes ciphertext. I found that ElGamal produces ciphertext that is 2 times keysize. So I would need to use 128bits keysize, which are not secure enough. I can use any keysize, but the ciphertext must not exceed 32bytes. Is it possible with other schemes?

Comment: Public key cryptography are never bandwidth-efficient. There's no solution whatsoever that meets your requirement. Your system/software/protocol/design must adapt.

Comment: For proper pk-crypto, the smallest (somewhat secure) overhead I'm aware of is around 40-48 bytes.

Comment: @SEJPM ECIES would get to 32 + 16 = 48 bytes using a compressed public point as key, but that would still be without message integrity / authentication of course.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yeah, 32 bytes should buy you a DH public key, e.g. with curve25519 and the 16 bytes buy you the CPA -> CCA2 upgrade. Sender authentication and replay protection is indeed a different beast.

Comment: I'm wondering a bit if you can use the static key pair to derive a public key for a ephemeral key pair giving a value of only 16 bytes. But at the moment it's just that: a thought experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to derive a shared key via DHKE. And then, encrypt the message with AES. Since the message is authenticated and I know its public key, I can use it to derive a shared key with DHKE, during decryption as well.